# YiiFramework - Code redundancy on model rule declaration

Tags: php, yii, yii-validation

would like to ask if is there a way that I can group multiple rules in the model into 1 so that i can reduce the amount of codes especially on places where same attribute needed to be check on multiple rules... Below is how the rules declaration now...

```
            array (
                    'new_email_addr',
                    'email',
                    'on' => 'chngEmail'
            ),
            array (
                    'new_email_addr',
                    'required',
                    'on' => 'chngEmail'
            ),
            array (
                    'new_email_addr',
                    'sameEmail',
                    'on' => 'chngEmail'
            ),
```

As you can see, the attribute **new_email_addr** needs to be check on 3 rules before it is save... What I wanted to achieve is something like this so i can do everything in one section.

```
            array (
                    'new_email_addr',
                    'required, email, sameEmail',
                    'on' => 'chngEmail'
            ),
```

Is there such possibilities?

Comment: You could create a custom validation rule that does all http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/168/create-your-own-validation-rule/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that is not possible. You can group several fields, scenarios, and exceptions together but not several validators (see [the definite guide](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/form.model#declaring-validation-rules) for examples).

The only way out were to create your custom validator combining the wanted ones as Samuel suggested.